# Issues with declaring and writing to arrays with Arduino and C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino

I'm messing around with an Arduino board for the first time.

I have an array declared like this (I know don't judge me), it's for storing each character of the LCD as a sort of cache:

```
char* lcd_characters[] = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
```

Then later on I'm trying to write to a specific slot of the array, like this, to save that letter to it:

```
new_char = String(message.charAt(i));
```

...blah blah blah...

```
lcd_characters[pos] = new_char; << error here
```

However it is giving me this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' in assignment
```

The funny thing is when I do this (below) it do assign the letter to it, however I have a var which is a single letter but can't assign it.

```
lcd_characters[pos] = "H";
```

Can someone help me out please. Thanks. I'm brand new to C and been ok so far.

Basically I want an  array of characters and then I want to write on the array positions with a new value.

Why does it even matter what type of string I'm writing to that array position, I should be able to write a number or boolean there too and call it later. Is there something wrong with the way the array is declared initially?

Edit:

I tried...

```
lcd_characters[pos] = new_char.c_str();
```

however that's giving me the similar error:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
```

Wtf? All I want to do is say this array position equals this new value. That's it. I've done this a million times in javascript, ruby, python (even php) etc. I just want to go, this array... x[12] equals my letter in new_char !!!! Ahh.

Comment: new_char = String(message.charAt(i)); // are you sure this is C ?

Comment: @Sevauk TBH it might be C++, it's my first day with it!

Comment: Then if it is C++, you are trying to assign a String object (new_char) to a char * type (lcd_character[pos]). You should learn about C++ objects.

Comment: @Sevauk how do I turn that string object into (a single text character object?!) so I can assign it to the array?

Comment: stringInstance.c_str() from Aloys response.

Comment: @Sevauk I edited it, that also threw an error.

Comment: try const char* lcd_characters[] = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};

Answer (score 4):

A few remarks:

1. Are you using C or C++? String is a C++ class, but you are creating a an array of c strings (`char *`).
2. You are creating an array of strings (`char* var[]` equals to `char**`), but your naming suggests you want an array of characters. A c string is basically an array of characters, so stick with that (`char *` or `char []`).

I would recommend you go for only C code in this case:

```
char lcdChars[4] = {' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}; // init with spaces
lcdChars[2] = 'x'; // write x to position 3
```

Note: A string in C++ can output a C string (`char *`) by calling `stringInstance.c_str()`.

Comment: Would `char lcdChar[3]={'0'}` not be a better idea? I have no idea what output you might expect for character 0 (is is a terminating char)?

Comment: Yes, so zero would mean "uninitialized" - but my question, as you edited, was setting buffer size!

Comment: @Aloys = 'x' worked all along, it was an issue with assigning the other newly created string to the array placement that is causing the error.